# View controller is not removing Notification Center observer

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, observer-pattern, nsnotificationcenter

I have this `viewDidLoad` code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];

   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];

   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                            selector:@selector(messageReceived:)
                                             name:@"messageReceived"
                                           object:nil];
}
```

This view controller is one of an `UITabBarController`. Every time I go to its tab, `viewDidLoad` is called, but it seems that `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];` does nothing and "messageReceived" is registered each time the method is called.

This code snippet from another class that notifies:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"messageReceived"
                                                            object:nil
                                                          userInfo:nil];
```

is called only once but, if for example, I go 3 times to the tab of the view controller that is observing and the `viewDidLoad` is called 3 times, then its `messageReceived:` method is also called 3 times...

What could I be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to hook the following:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                            selector:@selector(messageReceived:)
                                             name:@"messageReceived"
                                           object:nil];
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

when you tap on your tab bar, a new instance of your UIViewController gets created, hence the `viewDidLoad` that gets called.  When you call the `removeObserver` method from within `viewDidLoad`, you are asking to remove the newly created view controller from the observers, which at that point as never registered.

`-viewWillDisappear` is called before your view controller is removed from the view hierarchy, so calling `removeObserver` from that method should do the trick.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. What does it happen if I want to keep observing while the app is in background state? Is it possible/appropriate to handle that with Notification Center, or should I use local notifications?

Comment: In this case you probably want to have your AppDelegate or some other persistent controller to observe the notification instead of your view controller.

Comment: Thank you. Another question then arises from this: since this view controller I'm talking about is loaded always a user launches the app, and I've enabled background mode for location services, wouldn't this view controller be persisted as long as I keep observing for location updates?

Comment: Observing from any NSObject (including UIViewController) that persists while in background would do the trick to be honest.  So if your view controller stays loaded while in background then it shouldn't matter if you observe from AppDelegate or from the view controller.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add the "remove observer" code in dealloc method which will be called by arc automatically when your view will be removed also for background handling you can post notification from app delegate methods 'applicationWillEnterInBackground' and other methods ..